# Having issue to render html data in react native

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I'm having issue on how to render a HTML API data name description in my react native code. Currently, the API data is in HTML format: [HTML Format Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxnQ2.png) . I want to convert it to normal text like this: [Normal Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58b57.png). Please do help me out to solve this problem.

Given HTML API Data name: [Given API Data name Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwsTz.png)

This is my code:

```
 return (
            <ScrollView style={[GlobalStyle.CustomScrollView]}>
                <HeaderBar3/>
                <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventTitle]}> Event Details</Text>
                <View style={[GlobalStyle.EventDetailView]}>
                    <Image style={[GlobalStyle.EventDetailImage]} source={{uri: eventData.main_image}} resizeMode="contain"/>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventSubtitle]}>Date:</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventDate]}>{date}</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventTime]}>{startTime}{'-'}{endTime}</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventSubtitle]}>Venue:</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventDescr]}>{eventData.venue}</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventSubtitle]}>Ticket:</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventTicketPrice]}>{eventData.promotional_price}</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventSubtitle]}>Description:</Text>
                    <Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventDescr]}>{eventData.description}</Text>
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the HTML tags using `.replace()` method. Try this:

```js
<Text style={[GlobalStyle.EventDescr]}>{eventData.description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'')}</Text>
```

Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I got an error mentioning "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'eventData.description.replace')"